# Angular 2 fail to subscribe with shared service

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have some issues with BehaviorSubject. Here's shared service for three components:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class StageEndService {

  private stageNumber = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  private stageNumberPassed = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

  stageNumber$ = this.stageNumber.asObservable();
  stageNumberPassed$ = this.stageNumber.asObservable();

  announceStageNumber(num) {
    this.stageNumber.last(num);
  }

  announceStageNumberPassed(num) {
    this.stageNumberPassed.last(num);

  }
}
```

Here's first part of one of the two components that changes values in service:

```
import { StageEndService } from './../../../common/services/stage-end.service';

@Component({
...
providers: [StageEndService]
})

...
private value = 6;

constructor (private stageEndService: StageEndService) {

  this.stageEndService.announceStageNumber(value);

}
```

Second component is similar, but changes value of stageNumberPassed.

In my last component I'm trying to subscribe but fail (console.log returns 0):

```
import { StageEndService } from './../../../common/services/stage-end.service';

// there's no provider here since it's not necessary if I'm correct

 constructor(private stageEndService: StageEndService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.stageNumberSubscription = this.recruitmentEndService.stageNumber$.subscribe(response => {
  this.stageNumber = response;
});
```

No idea where's the problem. When I log values passed to function in service it  returns correct numbers. Don't know if that matters but just in case: last component (where I'm trying to subscribe) is grand-grandchildren of the first component where I'm setting new value for the first time.

Comment: What is `last(...)` supposed to do? To me it seams you meant to use `next()`

Comment: I'm not aware of .last() method so just saying to replace it with .next() or .emit().

Comment: By d way, which version are you using of angular2?

Comment: @micronyks Replaced with .next() and .emit(). Neither is working. I'm using RC5.

Answer (score 3):

Don't add the service to providers of each component. This way each component gets its own instance and you can't use it to communicate between services.

Only provide the service once in the `AppModule` or a shared parent component.

Comment: Done that and leave only imports but it didn't helped.

Comment: I had a very similar setup and problem. Was trying to toggle a menu through a "controller" which I had listed in the module's providers. Everything logged out as expected but the subscribe callback was never called. Removing it from here (and removing the injectable decorator) fixed it for me. Interestingly inspecting in Augury did reveal that the instance of the "controller", that my menu component was dependant on, never changed values. Still left with questions tho, how does listing the controller as a provider create new instances?

Comment: Registering a provider is all about creating instances. Angular DI creates an instance per provider. If you have more than one provider or one provider on a component where multiple instances are created, then you get as many instances of the service (controller). Where you provide it also determines which instance is injected where. Angular DI searches from the component (directive, pipe, service) that is requesting a dependency for providers at the component, then its parents, and if none was found yet in providers registered in modules.

Answer (score 1):

```
this.recruitmentEndService.stageNumber$.subscribe(response => {
  this.stageNumber = response;
});
```

should be

```
this.stageEndService.stageNumber$.subscribe(response => {
  this.stageNumber = response;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the problem must be somewhere else since neither of those didn't fix it.

Comment: Point 4 seems problematic in your case.

Comment: replacing `recruitmentEndService` by `stageEndService` shold resolve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the issue. I make mistake while preparing code sample when posting the question. Problem lies somewhere else. I just discovered that when there's only one component that emit value change it works perfectly fine. But when other component emit another value (using second function in the service) subscription is broken.